# I have no idea what I'm doing and need help please

Tags: uninstall, windows-10

Ok so my brother passed away a few months ago and left behind his asus computer my mom just bought him before he passed. He downloaded ubuntu or whatever on it and she wants me to clear everything off and reinstall windows so she can use it but I have no idea where to begin can anyone help me please?

Comment: I'm sure it would if I knew what they were talking about I am not tech savvy at all

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1084800/19626. Alternately, find a friend of yours who is tech savvy, and bake them a pie (or equivalent) in exchange for the afternoon they will spend installing Windows for you. Our family's going rate is one pie per afternoon. Friends must cook a dinner entree. Strangers must pay money.